# How can i return maximum number in range in Python

Tags: python

#### This is my formula in python

Implement the mathematical function f(x) = -5 x5 + 69 x2 - 47

#### Define the math function

```
def math_formula(x):

# This is the formula
    math_formula = -5 * (x**5) + 69 *(x**2) - 47
    return math_formula
```

#### Print the value in our range

```
for value in range (0,4):
    print 'For f(',(value),')', 'the number is:' , math_formula(value)

print ''    
print ('The the maximum of these four numbers is:'), max(math_formula(value))
```

The function returns the all numbers for f(0) to f(3).

Can someone answer the following question:
Why this print does not return the maximum number?

```
print ('The the maximum of these four numbers is:'), max(math_formula(value))
```

It returns the higher negative number in the range.
I have no idea how to return the max positive number. How to return the max positive number.

Comment: The documentation will be your red pill: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`max()` needs to work on a sequence. You need to pass it a list of all the calculations. Try this variation:

```
results = []
for value in range(0, 4):
    print 'For f(',(value),')', 'the number is:' , math_formula(value)
    results.append(math_formula(value)) # add the value to the list

print ''
print 'The maximum of these four numbers is:', max(results)
```

You can also simplify your `math_formula` method:

```
def math_formula(x):
    return -5 * (x**5) + 69 *(x**2) - 47
```

Answer (score 4):

```
max(math_formula(value) for value in range(0, 4))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
max((math_formula(value) for value in xrange(0,4)))
```

---

**EDIT**

For your interpreter:

```
max([math_formula(value) for value in range(0,4)])
```

Comment: Error: name 'xrange' is not defined

Comment: Just so you know i am using an online interpreter

http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user10_t4mgBNswzc_6.py

Comment: Check my edit. There is no xrange in this interpreter, and max doesn't accept generators.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use this      `max(a[i:i+k])`
to get the max within a range